# Console: cannot fill bottom and right area

Tags: c#, console

Can someone explain to me why there is an area on the bottom and the right of the console when I run this code, I can't select anything in the area, the code makes a rectangle without corners, this is an image of what it looks like for me:

[image: console window image]

EDIT: the area seems to only appear for me, it doesn't show on other's images even when I tried their code. Very weird.

EDIT 2: area highlighted in red:

[image: console window area highlighted]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int w = 50;
        int h = 10;

        Console.SetWindowSize(w, h);
        Console.SetBufferSize(w, h);

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w-2));

        for(int i = 0; i < h - 2; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i + 1);
            Console.Write("#" + new string(' ', w-2) + "#");
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, h-1);
        Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w - 2));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you comment out SetBufferSize line.

Comment: i provided an image of what it looks like to me,
when i comment out SetBufferSize it shows scroll bars and thats not what i want

Comment: Your image shows nothing weird, what do you mean by "area"? What exactly? Highlight in your image in red, or explain better.

Comment: i mean that in the console window there is an area to the right of all the characters and also below all the characters, i cant select that area with my mouse in the console window

Comment: i put a second image in the question with the area highligted in red

Comment: With that code, on my system, I get the exact same thing VilgotanL.  I cannot select the very rightmost column, or the very bottom most row.

Comment: finally someone that gets the same thing as me, but its still wierd why its only for some pepole

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Window size and the Buffer Size 1 char larger that your reference area. This allows to write all the chars that fill the area without triggering the scroll bars.

You omit to write the last char, in position `(w, h)`, otherwise the Console will scroll.
Then use [Console.MoveBufferArea()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.movebufferarea) to copy a char in the buffer to the last position. This method just uses the Buffer, it doesn't actually write to the Console, so the Console window won't scroll.

Replace the char moved by the function - writing to the Console this time - and the area is filled completely.

► **In case the Console shows *unrelated to the buffer-size* bands**:
if you haven't done this before, open the Console Properties from the Console Menu and select `Discard old duplicates` in the `Command History` section of the `Options` panel.
You can do that also setting the **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\HistoryNoDup`** value to `1` in the registry. I usually do that when a Console app starts and re-set the previous value when it closes (you just need to set it once - It's in the Current User branch, no need for admin rights).

[image: Console MoveBufferArea]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DrawConsoleArea(50, 10, '#', false);
}

internal static void DrawConsoleArea(int width, int height, char chr, bool showCursor)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = showCursor;

    Console.SetWindowSize(width + 1, height + 1);
    Console.SetBufferSize(width + 1, height + 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
        Console.Write(chr + new string(' ', width - 1) + chr);
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(new string(chr, width + 1));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, height);
    Console.Write(new string(chr, width));

    Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 0, 1, 1, width, height);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(chr);
}
```

Comment: when i run your code i still get that wierd area but on your image the area isnt there, the area is still there for me

Comment: Try to discard the old Buffer duplicates (it's in the Console's `Options` panel). Close and retry.

Comment: I've added a couple of notes about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I've not absolutely determined it is the case, but it seems to happen only when the size of the console window is decreased (it seems to work fine if you increase the size of the console window).

I found that clearing the console buffer corrects the problem. You can clear the console buffer by sending an escape sequence to it:

```
Console.Write('\x1b' + "[3J");
```

This escape sequence works in Windows, but I've not tested it on any other platform. I found information about this escape sequence here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences

If you change your sample to send that escape sequence after setting the console window and buffer sizes, it works:

```
HashBox(50, 10);
...
static void HashBox(int w, int h)
{
    Console.SetWindowSize(w, h);
    Console.SetBufferSize(w, h);
    Console.Write('\x1b' + "[3J"); //clear buffer

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w - 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < h - 2; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i + 1);
        Console.Write("#" + new string(' ', w - 2) + "#");
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, h - 1);
    Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w - 2));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I've developed an open-source library of console utilities that has a function to handle this automatically.
https://github.com/StrickTechnologies/Strick.PlusCon

```
using Strick.PlusCon.Models;
...
HashBox(50, 10);
...
static void HashBox(int w, int h)
{
    ConsoleSize.Set(w, h); //set console and buffer size, plus clear the buffer

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w - 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < h - 2; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i + 1);
        Console.Write("#" + new string(' ', w - 2) + "#");
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, h - 1);
    Console.Write(" " + new string('#', w - 2));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing the cursor from `Console.ReadKey();`

If you could increase your window height by 1 line and then push the cursor in the bottom.

```
Console.SetWindowSize(w, h+1);
Console.SetBufferSize(w, h+1);

//...

Console.WriteLine(" " + new string('#', w - 2));

Console.Write("Press any key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Or, hide the cursor visibility to false. Also, you might want to do ReadKey(true) otherwise the character pressed on a keyboard will be written in the corner.

However, make sure to make it visible afterward, in case you need it to be visible in any user interactions.

```
Console.CursorVisible = false;
Console.ReadKey(true);

//...

Console.CursorVisible = true;
```

Edit with images:
With your code:
[image: With your code]

With `Console.CursorVisible = false;`
[image: With Cursor Visible false]

Comment: There is still that area on both the bottom and right of my console window, look at the image i linked in the question

Comment: it seems like the area only appears for me, on everyone else's images it doesnt show the area

Comment: I looked at the image you attached. The "_" blinking is not a "Weird." It is the console cursor. I get that as well when I execute your code. It doesn't appear when I set Console.CursorVisible = false;

Comment: that's not what im saying is wierd, on my image to the right of the cursor and below it is a black area that doesnt appear on other's images, my console window is slightly bigger than others for some reason

Comment: You mean the empty space?
You could set the buffer size 1 size up, but then a scrollbar will appear.
Console.SetWindowSize(w, h);
Console.SetBufferSize(w+1, h+1);

Comment: Yes the empty space is what i mean, but i dont want scrollbars